# NTL library GF2X

Tags: c++, polynomial-math, polynomials, ntl

I am experimenting with the Galois Field using the NTL library. `GF2` are the integers mod 2, `GF2X` are polynomials over `GF2` and `GF2E` is the ring/field extension over `GF2`.

The problem that I am facing is that I initialize the irreducible polynomial as follows

```
GF2X irreduc;
SetCoeff(irreduc, 128, 1);
SetCoeff(irreduc, 7, 1);
SetCoeff(irreduc, 2, 1);
SetCoeff(irreduc, 1, 1);
SetCoeff(irreduc, 0, 1);
GF2E::init(irreduc);
```

and then I also initialize two polynomials:

```
GF2X a; 
SetCoeff(a, 120);
SetCoeff(a, 22);

GF2X b;
SetCoeff(b, 128);
SetCoeff(b, 51);

std::cout << "a: " << a << '\n';
std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';
```

and multiply them:

```
std::cout << "\ndeg(a * b): " << deg(a * b) << '\n';
```

The output is `deg(a * b):` **248**, which is out of the field/ring of the `2^128`, defined by the irreducible polynomial.

I know that I am probably missing something obvious but I am very new to this area so bear with me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said, `GF2X` represents polynomials over `GF2`, so they do not get reduced by the polynomial you initialized GF2E with. You need to convert the polynomials to `GF2E` and then everything works as expected.

So changing you last line to

```
std::cout << "\ndeg(a * b): " << deg(conv<GF2X>(conv<GF2E>(a) * conv<GF2E>(b))) << '\n';
```

results in the output

```
deg(a * b): 124
```

This conversions are pretty ugly. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it and the way NTL is documented it is hard to find the right functions for what you want to do. I only found `GF2E::degree()`, but this only gives you the degree if the irreducible polynomial. Let me know when you find the right way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! I will edit the question if I come across a better solution.